# Restrict WiX MSI From Running On Its Own

Tags: wix

In my company I create apps that are shared by many different products. For instance a help application.

A requirement is that I create an MSI with WiX that can be consumed by the main installers for each product. This MSI receives variables from the main installers so that it installs and uninstalls properly.

Because of this, I want to restrict having the MSI run by itself. That is, someone double clicking on it, etc.

Is there a way I can prevent it from running on its own and display a message of some type to the user?

I am completely new to WiX and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that with the presence of tools that look inside .msi files, edit them, and/or create transforms, nothing is 100% foolproof. But assuming you only want to prevent accidental misuse, Calum's approach is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a public property which blocks the installation of the product by default - i.e. if a user were to attempt to install it by double-clicking.

```
<Condition Message="test">BLOCKINSTALL = 1</Condition>
<Property Id="BLOCKINSTALL" Value="0"/>
```

This blocks install by default. The property can then be changed by your other installers, or by calling:

```
msiexec /package Installer.msi BLOCKINSTALL=1
```

This will allow you to change the blocking value, allowing the installation to progress.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a big help.